# I want to write a sed (or awk) command to replace a string from one file with the entire contents of another file please check

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
cat file.txt 
TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3
```

```
cat other_file.txt 
there are multiple lines1.
there are multiple lines2.
there are multiple lines3
```

I want the following output :

```
cat file3.txt 
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines1
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines2
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines3
```

replace `multiple` key word with all the content from file on each line hope this is clear

Comment: Can `file.txt` contain multiple lines? How would the output look like in this case? Can a line in `other_file.txt` contain `multiple` more than once? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: yes file.txt have multiple lines and other_file.txt contain "multiple" more than once in every line . i hope i am clear now

Comment: Please show an additional example that has more than one line in `file.txt` and more than one occurrence of `multiple` in `other_file.txt` and the expected output for this case. Please clarify if the last line in `file.txt` is terminated with a newline or not and what should happen with the newline character(s).

Comment: Please don't post the same question again: instead ***edit*** your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
sed '1h;1d;G;s/multiple\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/;P;d' file.txt other_file.txt > file3.txt
```

Do I need to explain?

Comment: giving output like below

Comment: giving output like below  there are TEXT1  lines1.  there are TEXT1  lines2.  there are TEXT1  lines3.  i want output like below   there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines1
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines2
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines3

Comment: @user535186 The `sed` solution provided works perfectly in my system `sed (GNU sed) 4.8`. If the output in your system does not provide the required results, maybe you are using a different `sed` version.

Comment: There can't be no version dependence in here. Nothing would remove some parts of the line without reason. I suspect the OP actually uses different data.

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU Awk 5.1.0`, bellow code will produce what you describe.

```
cat file1
TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3

cat file2
there are multiple lines1.
there are multiple lines2.
there are multiple lines3.

awk 'NR==FNR{a=$0;next}{$3=a}1' file1 file2
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines1.
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines2.
there are TEXT1 TEST2 TEST3 lines3.
```

Short explanation:
`NR==FNR` : Quick way of awk to compare NR (global record number) to FNR (record number of processed file). NR equals to FNR only for the very first file.

`a=$0`: `$0` holds the whole record / line and this is stored in a variable called `a`

`next`: Says to `awk` to read the next record/line of the file.

So this part of code is executed only for the very first file fed to awk, meaning file1:
`NR==FNR{a=$0;next}`
PS: If your first file has more than one lines, then variable `a` will hold the contents of the last record/last line of file1.

This piece of code is executed on the second file (file2):
`{$3=a}1`

`$3=a`: Replaces `$3` (3rd field of input) with the contents of variable `a`. If the word `multiple` is not always on the 3rd field of input line of file2 , obviously this solution will fail.
Alternatively you can use something like `{sub("multiple",a)}1` to literally replace the word `multiple` with the contents of variable `a`.

`1` : Just prints the current record/line